How to make sure my public facing react application is not exposing my backend application endpoints?
I have a react application for the frontend and an express application for the back end. The application is a public facing application, where the user does not have to login and onload, there is a call to the database to retrieve some data.
There is a collection of client Ids and secrets in the database, so third party applications will use this to make a call to a token endpoint that generates a token and sends it back for them so that they can access the other endpoints.
I did this for my application as well, however my QA said it seems unsecure to be seeing the client id and secret inside the body of the request.
Is that really unsecure? should I put it in the header as basic authentication? I was thinking that if I copy and paste that and decode it from the base64 then I can just as easily see the client id and secret.
I tried to use my backend as a proxy as well, so the frontend is making calls like api/users/<id> instead of https://example.com/users/<id>. Testing this route, I created environment variables inside the backend with the client id and secret for my application which onload will just make the call to authenticate my frontend on its behalf and place the token in a cookie which would be used for subsequent requests.
However, we found later on that when a call is made to the authentication endpoint that sets the cookie, it is always successful, and the cookie is set.
I have cors set on my frontend with my frontend application's specific domain, however I am wondering how secure this it.
Please let me know your opinions on this and if my approach is flawed.
How can I make sure that only my application is able to access this data via my backend?
